# Keeping apps synchronized

Tags: integration, webhooks, crm, erp

Need to integrate two services(e-shop cms with erp). When the order created in shop, it should appear in erp, and erp changes should be visible in cms.
How do I control deliever of webhook? Tech support said, that they send webhook once, no que, or another attempt to send.
Maybe instead of listening for webhook, I should get updates by API, and synchronize somehow in my app?

Should I write my webapp to glue, or better use framework?

Comment: "order created in shop" - What does this mean? Where is the actual data stored? I assume a database? Why isn't or can't ERP / CRM be querying this database to find the same order data?

Comment: I meant when someone made order in shop, cms create an order. And you can get it by API or it can send webhook.
Those are two separated services with own databases. I should not touch database or edit erp, crm. They have API and can send webhook. Sorry for bad english, is that make sense now?

Comment: Calling APIs or introducing any HTTP methods will introduce eventual consistency with asynchrony and potentially dropped records via timeouts and connection resets... If you really want to sync systems of record, then change-data-capture (CDC) or replication directly against the database(s) is the better way to accomplish this

Comment: Oh, no need in such perfect sync. Need to keep that no changes are missed. Maybe I can poll APIs like once in a minute.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.